# javascript slideshow's recursive function not working

Tags: javascript, recursion

I don't know why the if statement doesn't work.

```
    <script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
function slideShow(){
    var images= document.getElementsByClassName('slider-box')[0].getElementsByTagName('img');

    images[slideIndex].classList.remove('show-slide');
    if(slideIndex > images.length-1)
        slideIndex = 0;

    slideIndex++;
    images[slideIndex].classList.add('show-slide');

    setInterval(slideShow,2000);
}
      slideShow();
</script>
```

I have 3 images in HTML .

The variable slideIndex  goes up to 3 and  stays at 3.

Comment: you want `setTimeout()` not `setInterval()`

Comment: either what Pointy said, or move the setInterval outside the slideShow function. Because setInterval keeps running the function, where setTimeout delays the execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) as it isn't properly supported:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var sliderIndex = 0;

function slide() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slider.children.length; i++) {
    var cls = slider.children[i].getAttribute("class").replace(/.show/ig, '');
    slider.children[i].setAttribute("class", cls);
  }

  slider.children[sliderIndex].setAttribute(
    "class",
    slider.children[sliderIndex].getAttribute("class") + " show"
  );

  sliderIndex++;
  if (sliderIndex > slider.children.length - 1) {
    sliderIndex = 0;
  }
}
slide();
setInterval(slide, 3000);
```

```css
#slider {} #slider .slide {
  position: absolute;
  -moz-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
  transition: all 1s linear 0s;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0) !important;
}
#slider .slide.show {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <img class="slide" src="http://placehold.it/310x150/E8117F/000000?text=1" />
  <img class="slide" src="http://placehold.it/310x150/7812E5/000000?text=2" />
  <img class="slide" src="http://placehold.it/310x150/128AE5/000000?text=3" />
  <img class="slide" src="http://placehold.it/310x150/12E594/000000?text=4" />
  <img class="slide" src="http://placehold.it/310x150/E5B412/000000?text=5" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
function slideShow(){
    var images= document.getElementsByClassName('slider-box')[0].getElementsByTagName('img');

    images[slideIndex].classList.remove('show-slide');

    slideIndex++;
    if(slideIndex > images.length) slideIndex = 0;
    images[slideIndex].classList.add('show-slide');

    setInterval(slideShow,2000);
}
slideShow();
</script>
```

Comment: for the answer to be truly usefull, you should add some more information. Besides there is still a mistake in the code. You should either move setInterval outside the slideshow function or change it for setTimeout. otherwise the slideShow function will be called more and more